# How to Load Multiple Images into android image gallery?

Tags: android, image, url, gallery

I want to load heaps of images from a URL into my gallery.
At the moment they are stored in the drawable directory but i want to load them from a URL link like http://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa216/example/color.jpg instead of @drawable/image1

Here is the code i have.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                />

            <TextView
                style="@style/ImageTitle"
                android:text="@string/image1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image2" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/ImageTitle"
                android:text="@string/image2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image3" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/ImageTitle"
                android:text="@string/image3" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image4" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/ImageTitle"
                android:text="@string/image4" />
        </RelativeLayout>
 </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/ButtonContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/media_play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/media_pause" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/swipe_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowleft" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/swipe_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowright" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uae [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) Library from Github.

Download the project as zip & import the library in your project. Then from your java class,

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_view) 
String imageUrl = "your_url";  
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); 
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));              
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView);
```

Comment: I'm teaching my self to code so i dont know much but how would i implement that because i'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check it!

Comment: i've added the Universal Image Loader but and implemented your code but i get a complier error that "cannot find symbol context"

Comment: replace context with YourActivityName.this

Comment: Yes i am. its now compiling but nothing appears, its just a black

Comment: please, try in this way.

Comment: I've added your code and here is what it looks like http://pastebin.com/zsqE3z2K but it's saying cannot find imageView1 which is my image view the url is appearing in

Comment: It's because you forgot to initiate your image_view.

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_view); add this one too.

Comment: Yes its working now and also for all the other image views. Thank you so much for your help, its greatly appreciated. May God Bless you abundantly.

Comment: Good to know :) Can you please accept it as a answer? It may help others :)

Comment: How about implementing a saving functionality ? Save the images from the app to your device

Comment: Its already saved in your cache for future use, so that you dont have to download it again. Look at **onLoadingComplete** method of your **AnimateFirstDisplayListener** class. IF you want to do some additional things, you can do it there too.

Comment: like for someone using the app to save the picture to their sd-card

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Universal image loader` library

http://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
ImageView imageView = ... // view, where the image will be displayed
String imageUrl = ... // image URL 
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView);
```

It is very easy to use and takes care of most of the things like caching etc

If you do not want to use any external libraries, You can write your own code to download and display image too.

Follow this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Comment: I'm teaching my self to code so i dont know much but how would i implement that because i'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Jus google it.`how to use universal image loader.`You will get many tutorials and articles

Comment: Yeah i have and i'm working through it, i'll let you know if i get stuck. Your help is been greatly appreciated

Comment: I get a "cannot find symbol context error when i compile the project and i can't figure what the issue is

Comment: Update your question with the latest code that you have implemented

Comment: Update your java code in your question itself by editing the question

Comment: All i've done is changed the first image view and gave it the name imageview1